# Areas in mvc3 .Does it make sense to use them?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am building an asp.net mvc3 application and I have decided to use areas and wondering if it's a good idea.
Yes they should provide separation but they are still in your main project.
How do you build a project with modules(EG Orchard) what is the approach.Any tutorials?

Please note that I am new to web (winform guy) so bear with me.

I have now a problem with areas? I am getting javascript errors as if it cannot find them?
eg "$ is undefined " etc... Are you supposed to have the reference to the javascript folder?
Why I am getting errors in areas and not in the other parts of the web app?

THanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use areas. I have an Admin area inside my application, and Areas in MVC works just fine for me.

Regarding the JavaScript errors, I think the problem is the reference to the JavaScript files from your Area's Layout/Master file. The reference may be relative?

You probably want to refer to them as `/Scripts/MyJavaScriptFile.js` - given that the JavaScript files is located in a folder called `Scripts` in the root of your application. Not inside the Area's folder structure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.At the minute I dont have a layout for my area (Admin) I am about to add one.are you saying that in my layout this will not work <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> and i should remove the "~" for the reasons you mentioned.Also Do I need to add a layout declaration to each view in my area? EG  Layout="~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";

Comment: The script reference looks fine. The problem is not that then. If you have a file called `_ViewStart.cshtml` located in the `~/Views` folder, you shouldn't set the Layout in the actual Views. Those would simply inherit that of the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file. I assume you created an ASP.NET MVC 3 project using the Razor syntax. Then all Layout and `_ViewStart.cshtml` stuff should be set up correctly already.

Answer (score 0):

Areas are helpful for bigger sites. They help separate the site in different... areas(!):  Subdirectories of your site (from URL point of view).

Admin is probably the most common area: It contains several actions/views gathered in their own `admin/` subdir of your site.